# How to diagnose reason of blocking in fltmgr.sys (HDD access slow) in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, performance

My Windows 7 PC is blocking quite often for a couple of seconds up to half a minute or so. I tried to find the problem with the [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) by filtering all system calls that take over 2 seconds and find that these always have the following stacktrace segment:

```
0   fltmgr.sys  FltAcquirePushLockShared
1   fltmgr.sys  FltIsCallbackDataDirty
2   fltmgr.sys  fltmgr.sys
```

The next frame is NtCreateFile in most cases. The calls take often 2-10  seconds, but sometimes up to 50 seconds on a nearly idle system. The HDD (actually, a solid state disc) does not seem to be the problem - [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/) shows no problems in the benchmark and the error scan, and [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) also gives no hint of unusual CPU or IO activity. And I am pretty certain it is not a virus or something. :-)

How can I find out the actual problem? Are there any helpful tools?

Answer (score 0):

Use xperf from the WPT (part of the Windows 8 SDK) to trace disk IO:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306075534/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ntdebugging/archive/2009/08/17/xperf-to-investigate-slow-i-o-issues.aspx)

Run the script, minimize the CMD Window and when you have the issue again, go back to the cmd, wait 15-20s, press a key to stop logging. Open it with xperfview and look in the Disk IO graph which processes causes the high disk IO.

Comment: The annoying thing is: there is no high IO or CPU activity. I checked that with process explorer. (I extended the question a little to make that clear.) So that probably would not help, would it?

Comment: try it out and look if it helps or not.